# Multiple legends for a ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have seen existing treads but i couldnt correct my code. I have to divide the legend "Segmentation" into two different legends. One legend should be showing (Run,Walk) and other legend should be telling the StayPoint(Yes, No). Issue is that, all the legend values gets mixed up and comes under the same legend heading. Can anyone tell me about it ? Thank you !

```
   ll_meanstt <- sapply(total_trajectory[1:2], mean)
   sq_map2tt <- get_map(location = ll_meanstt,  maptype = "roadmap", source 
   = "google", zoom = 21)
  sisquoctt <- 
  setNames(data.frame(total_trajectory$tt_lon,total_trajectory$tt_lat, 
  total_trajectory$tt_ids, total_trajectory$Trajectory_Segmentation, 
  total_trajectory$tt_speed, Staypoint), c("lon", "lat", "LocationID", 
  "Segmentation", "SpeedMetersPerSecond", "Staypoint"));



ggmap(sq_map2tt) + 
geom_point(data = sisquoctt, size = 12,  aes(fill = Staypoint, shape = 
Staypoint)) +

geom_point(data = sisquoctt, size = 8,  aes(fill = Segmentation, shape = 
Segmentation)) +

geom_line(data = sisquoctt, size = 3,  aes(color =SpeedMetersPerSecond)) +
geom_label_repel (data = sisquoctt, aes(label = paste("", 

as.character(LocationID), sep="")), 
                  angle = 60, hjust = 2, color = "indianred3",size = 4)

        lon      lat    LocationID Segmentation SpeedMetersPerSecond Staypoint
  1  5.010633 47.29399      W5232         Walk                  1.2        No
  2  5.010643 47.29400      W5769         Walk                  1.0       Yes
  3  5.010716 47.29398      W5234          Run                  1.5        No
```

[image]

Comment: Do not post your data as an image, please learn how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Comment: I have updated my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have called `geom_point()` twice for data in the same x, y location and assigned the same aesthetics (fill and shape) to both Staypoint and Segmentation, so ggplot is putting them in the same legend. If you specify `fill =` for one variable, and `shape =` for the other, they should go into different legends. Also, not all points have `fill` aesthetics, you need to either select shapes that do(shapes 21 - 25 have `fill`), or use `color =`, an aesthetic that all ggplot2 points have.

Example using `color` instead of `fill`

```
ggmap(sq_map2tt) + 
geom_point(data = sisquoctt, size = 8,  aes(color = Staypoint, shape = Segmentation)) + 
geom_line(data = sisquoctt, size = 3,  aes(color = SpeedMetersPerSecond))
```

another approach if you want to use `fill` instead of `color`

```
ggmap(sq_map2tt) + 
    geom_point(data = sisquoctt, size = 8,  aes(fill = Staypoint, shape = Segmentation)) + 
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24) +
    geom_line(data = sisquoctt, size = 3,  aes(color = SpeedMetersPerSecond))
```